# Restrict a full shift to a compact and invariant set is subshift of finite type

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider the set $\Sigma_m = \{0,1,2,,,m-1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ consisting of all two-sided sequences of elements in $\{0,1,2,...,m-1\}$. Let $T:\Sigma_m \to \Sigma_m $ be the left shift, which is a homeomorphism, i.e. $T(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}=(x_{n+1})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}.$

Let $A \subset \Sigma_m$ be a non-empty compact, closed and $T$-invariant set. Is it true that $T|_{A}:A \to A$ is subshift of finite type?  By definition, it is subshift, but I don't know whether it is a subshift of finite type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no; not all subshifts are of finite type.

---

As you declared a subshift on $m$ symbols is a closed shift invariant subset of $\Sigma_m$. One way to define subshifts is by declaring taboos. More precisely, denote by $W_m$ the set of all words in (i.e. tuples of) $m$ symbols (the set of which we fix as $\underline{m}=\{0,1,...,m-1\}$ throughout). Then for any subset $\mathcal{T}\subseteq W_m$, denote by $\Sigma_m(\mathcal{T})$ the subset of $\Sigma_m$ that consists of bi-infinite sequences that do not contain any word in $\mathcal{T}$. It's straightforward to see that $\Sigma_m(\mathcal{T})$ is a subshift for any subset $\mathcal{T}$ of words. Further, any subshift is of this form, so that we have a surjective map

$$\mathcal{P}(W_m)\to \operatorname{Sub}_m, \mathcal{T}\mapsto \Sigma_m(\mathcal{T}).$$

(Here the domain is the power set of $W_m$ and the codomain is the collection of all subshifts on $m$ symbols.)

Note that this map is not surjective (when $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$); that is, there may be multiple taboo collections that define the same subshift. A subshift $S\in\operatorname{Sub}_m$ is said to be **of finite type** if for some finite $\mathcal{T}\in\mathcal{P}(W_m)$, $S=\Sigma_m(\mathcal{T})$.

(I believe it's a nice exercise to work through how the above map works with set operations on the LHS.)

---

The standard example of a subshift that is not of finite type is the so-called **even shift**, due to B. Weiss (from his paper "Subshifts of Finite Type and Sofic Systems").

**Ex (Even Shift):** Put $m=2$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{1\,0\,1,1\,000\,1,1\,00000\,1,1\,0000000\,1,..., 1\, 0^{2n+1}\, 1,...\}$, that is, it's taboo to have an odd number of $0$'s between any two $1$'s.

Here is another example of a subshift that is not of finite type:

**Ex (Context Free Shift):** Put $m=3$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{0\, 1^\alpha\, 2^\beta\, 0\,|\, \alpha\neq\beta\}$, that is, it's taboo to have a block of $1$'s followed by a block of $2$'s between any two $0$'s, except when the two blocks are of the same length.

---

As a final remark I should mention that the two examples of subshifts not of finite type can be distinguished; the even shift is the next best thing after finite type; it's an example of a sofic shift (a sofic shift is by definition a factor of a subshift of finite type). The context free shift fails to be a sofic shift. Here is a related Venn diagram:

[image]

(I took this from Lind & Marcus' book *An Introduction to Symbolic Dynamics and Coding* (p.69), which is the standard reference for symbolic dynamics ("for its own sake", let's say).)

(For completeness the **golden mean shift** is defined by $m=2$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{11\}$.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506649/169085

Comment: Thank you very much for your proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have observed that $A$ must be a subshift, so here is a different question: is *every* subshift necessarily a shift of finite type? If you can find an example of a subshift which is *not* a shift of finite type, then you have your answer.